# Monero April 6 Hardfork guide?

Tags: hard-fork

I mine Monero, and use the GUI wallet. I know updating the miner should be pretty straight forward, but the wallet? Will I keep the old blockchain? Where will I find the update? Should I move my balance out of the wallet? I know so many questions...maybe someone could post a guide or something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use ready made binaries, these will be available soon (in the next few days) on getmonero.org.

You will not need to replace your blockchain, nor move your monero. Just start using the new version when it's out.